# What are comparative operators in C?

Tags: c, operators

On my midterm there was a question that I believe has two correct answers, A and B. The question states:

> Which of the following sets of operators is composed only of comparative operators?
> A) >, <, >=, <=
> B) ==, !=
> C) &&, ||, !
> D) None of the above.

Page 235 of my textbook (Computer Science: A Structured Programming Approach Using C by Forouzan and Gilberg) states,

> C provides six comparative operators. … The operators are shown in Figure 5-4.

Figure 5-4 shows the operators <, <=, >, >=, ==, and !=. I emailed this to my lecturer and she responded with:

> I understand the point you made in your submitted paper, but the best course of action is to stick to CS159 notes packet rather than Forouzan's textbook, as the textbook is considered a supplemental resource for this course.

Page 119 of my notes packet (Purdue University's CS159 notes packet) says that comparative operators are == and !=. So does comparative operator have two definitions? Even in that case the question would have two correct answers.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/expressions, especially https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_comparison

Comment: I agree with you, I would have said A) and B). To me the response of the lecturer shows that she doesn't really know the subject she's teaching and just repeating whatever it is on the lecturer notes/slides. Out of curiosity, what does the notes packet say what kind of operator are `<`, `>`, etc.?

Comment: I'm actually in a Java class right now, and let me just say that schools and departments and teachers/professors all have their different outlook on the same concepts. If your professor tells you that comparative operators are `==` and `!=` then those are the only comparative operators. However, it's generally agreeable that comparative operators are operators that compare values, so `>`, `<`, `<=`, `>=`, and in C++20, `<=>` can be considered comparative operators as well when communicating in the real world with other people.

Comment: Are comparison operators the same thing as comparative operators?

Comment: The reference of _Comparison operators_ distinguishes between _Relational (<, <=, >, >=)_ and _Equality (==, !=)_ operators. So yes, two correct (different) answers.

Comment: The notes packet says that <, <=, >, and >= are relational operators

Comment: I believe the C standard uses the terms "relational operators" (for <, <=, >, >=) and "equality operators" (for == and !=).  It sounds like your course is adopting nonstandard terminology, then testing you on your understanding of that terminology.  I would stick to the standard.

Comment: Hmm in the big scheme of things, I find the distinction not really helpful to be honest. Perhaps I'm not right in claiming "the lecturer doesn't really know the subject", but I don't understand what's the point in these kind of questions.

Comment: "but the best course of action is to stick to CS159 notes packet rather than Forouzan's textbook," --> "but the best course of action is to stick to **the C standard**  rather than Forouzan's textbook,"

Comment: Email your lecturer: "notes packet and Forouzan's textbook are not C standard documents. C standard uses its own terminology which notes and textbook authors should learn before writing them

Comment: Update: I emailed my lecturer:

"It seems like there is a good argument for both sides, but why are we defining nonstandard terminology for something that already has a standard name? == and != official names are the equality operators."

Answer (score 4):

[§6.5.8 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.8) defines the operators `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=` to be the "relational operators".

[§6.5.9 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.9) defines the operators `==` and `!=` to be the "equality operators".

The ISO C standard does not use the terms "comparative operators" or "comparison operators", so it also does not provide a definition for them.

However, all six of the operators mentioned above are intended for comparing both operands, so the most meaningful definition of such a term would include all six of these operators.

Comment: This. If the exam is about C, then it does not have a correct answer. But looks like the exam is about lecture notes and not about C.

Answer (score 2):

C defines

4 Relational operators: `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`

and

2 Equality operators: `==`, `!=`.

C does not define *comparative operator*.

So unless you have some other source defining *comparative operator*, there is no definitive answer.

---

[@Tom Karzes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74661977/what-are-comparative-operators-in-c#comment131783560_74661977) makes a good point: "... your course is adopting nonstandard terminology, then testing you on your understanding of that terminology. I would stick to the standard."